# jqgrid: Why am I reveiving "eData" instead of the id attribute value?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jqgrid

jqgrid snippet:

```
gridComplete: function(){

    var ids = jQuery("#breed_list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++)
    {
        var cl = ids[i];
        ed = "<img src="../images/edit.png" alt="Edit" onclick="jQuery('#breed_list').editRow('"+cl+"');" />";
        de = "<img class="del_row" src="../images/delete.png" alt="Delete" />";
        ce = "<input class="del_row" type='button' onclick="deleteRow()" />";
        jQuery("#breed_list").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:ed+de+ce});
    }

    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        var valId = $('.ui-state-hover').attr("id");
        jQuery("#breed_list").setSelection(valId, false);
        alert(valId);
        //deleteRow(valId)
    });
```

Custom function code:

```
function deleteRow(){

    // Get the currently selected row
    var toDelete = $("#breed_list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');

    // You'll get a pop-up confirmation dialog, and if you say yes,
    // it will call "delete.php" on your server.
    $("#breed_list").jqGrid(
        'delGridRow',
        toDelete,
          {
               url: 'delete.php',
               reloadAfterSubmit:false
          }
    );
    //alert(toDelete);

}
```

That code auto selects the hovered cell correctly when delGridRow is NOT executed.  When I click the button under the actions column it calls the deleteRow() function which executes delGridRow. When I click cancel the delete form closes.  Now, when I hover a cell it does NOT auto select the current hovered cell.  To debug this I placed alert(valId) in the .mouseover function which returns eData instead of the id attribute value.  alert(valId) alerts out the id attribute value as long as the deleteRow function is not executed.  Why is eData set to valId when it should return the id attribute value? How do I fix this issue?

***EDIT***
Apparently I have been going about this the hard way.  I went back to the basic grid and gridComplete.

jQgrid snippet:

```
de = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='d' onclick=\"deleteRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
```

deleteRow function code:

```
function deleteRow(valId){

    jQuery("#breed_list").setSelection(valId, false);

    // You'll get a pop-up confirmation dialog, and if you say yes,
    // it will call "delete.php" on your server.
    $("#breed_list").jqGrid(
        'delGridRow',
        valId,
          { 
               url: 'delete.php',
               reloadAfterSubmit:false
          }
    );
    //alert(toDelete);

}
```

Works like a charm now, but I would still like to incorporate the mousehover feature as explained before.

Comment: Go to the answers people have submitted for all of your questions, and click the check mark to accept an answer

Comment: You know, I've been meaning to up other's credibility, but did not know how to accomplish that.  Now I do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have been going about this the hard way.  I went back to the basic grid and gridComplete.

jQgrid snippet:

```
    de = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='d' onclick=\"deleteRow('"+cl+"');\" />";

deleteRow function code:  

    function deleteRow(valId){

        jQuery("#breed_list").setSelection(valId, false);

        // You'll get a pop-up confirmation dialog, and if you say yes,
        // it will call "delete.php" on your server.
        $("#breed_list").jqGrid(
            'delGridRow',
            valId,
              { 
                   url: 'delete.php',
                   reloadAfterSubmit:false
              }
        );
        //alert(toDelete);

    }
```

Works like a charm now, but I would still like to incorporate the mousehover feature as explained before.